# How to bring up Broadcom NetXtreme 57504 Quad-Port Interfaces?

Tags: networking, drivers, server, kernel, broadcom

I'm setting up a Cluster of servers.

They're Dell R650 with an Intel CPU. There are 2 network cards per server. Two builtin 1G ports and a 4-port Broadcom card with 25GBs with SFP28-Slots.

We bought generic [direct-attach-cables](https://www.fs.com/de/products/106789.html) from fs.com to use with these cards.
These cables are not on the "officially supported" [list](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/storage-and-ethernet-connectivity/ethernet-nic-controllers/bcm957xxx/1-0/installation_3/connecting-the-network-cables.html), but hey, they're just direct-attach-cables, right? According to [this document](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/957504-N425G-DS), copper-DACs should work for the adapter.

Each server has two of these cables running to each other server and the leds indicating link-status actually come on. iDRAC also reports the links as up with a negotiated speed of 25Gb/s. It also reports that packets are being sent and received on this link and no errors have occured.

However, when booting up Ubuntu 20 LTS, which is on the [list of supported OSes](https://www.dell.com/support/home/de-de/drivers/supportedos/poweredge-r650) for this server (or 22 LTS, which isn’t) i can not bring up any of the interfaces this device offers through the bnxt_en-driver. This is what i'm trying to do:

```
$: ip addr add 172.16.0.1/24 dev eno12399np0
$: ip link set dev eno12399np0 up
RTNETLINK answers: No space left on device
```

This action also results in the following three lines in the kernel log:

```
bnxt_en 0000:51:00.0 eno12399np0: hwrm req_type 0x90 seq id 0xe8 error 0x4
bnxt_en 0000:51:00.0 eno12399np0: HWRM vnic filter failure rc: ffffffe4
bnxt_en 0000:51:00.0 eno12399np0: bnxt_init_nic err: ffffffe4
```

and the link status reported by `ip link` remains "DOWN"

I've installed Ubuntus mainline kernel 5.18.3 to see if it changes anything, but i get the same error. I have also updated the network card’s firmware to the latest version.

What am i doing wrong? Is this a kernel-bug? Are my cables unsupported? What else can i test?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i had activated the option for flow-offloading (linux DPDK) in the network card’s firmware settings. Disabling that option made the links work properly in linux.